# Django forloop on Queryset returning same user

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have created a queryset in Django to filter by location.

1) If a location is not typed in, the page should display all users.

2) If a location is typed in and it matches another user, only that user should be shown.

I am running a forloop on the queryset to populate the page with users which match the filter.

Right now, the page is returning the same user twice and not showing any of the other users.

Here is an image. [image: problem]

Would anybody be able to diagnose what is going wrong?

I have omitted code that is not relevant.

filters.py

```
import django_filters
from .models import Profile

class ProfileFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = {
            'city': ['iexact'],
        }
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def profile_filter(request):
    f = ProfileFilter(request.GET, queryset=Profile.objects.all())
    return render(request, 'profile/profile_filter.html', {'filter': f})
```

filter.html

```
{% for profile in filter.qs %}
                  <img class="img-thumbnail account-img center" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ user.profile.image.url }}" width="100" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" alt="Card image cap">
                      <div class="card-body padding-success">
                            <h3 class="marker">{{ user.first_name }} {{ user.last_name }}</h3>
                            <h3 class="marker">City: {{ user.profile.city }}</h3>
                            <br><button type="submit" class="small" value="submit" href="{% url 'register' %}">Message?</button>
                      </div>
                </div>
          {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't reference the profiles in your filter at all within the for loop; you use `user`, which is automatically populated with the value of the current logged-in user. You should use the variable you define in your for loop, `profile`.

```
{% for profile in filter.qs %}
      <img class="img-thumbnail account-img center" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ profile.image.url }}" width="100" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body padding-success">
                <h3 class="marker">{{ profile.user.first_name }} {{ user.last_name }}</h3>
                <h3 class="marker">City: {{ profile.city }}</h3>
                <br><button type="submit" class="small" value="submit" href="{% url 'register' %}">Message?</button>
          </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Many thanks. I'm still learning and am pretty new, I was getting confused about profile inheriting from user and using `user.profile.city` instead of just `profile.city` which is why the forloop obviously didn't find it!